# Cannot find geth command

Tags: ubuntu

I have followed the instructions on the following website (https://chainskills.com/2017/02/24/create-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-with-iot-devices-16/) to install geth Ethereum client on a Raspberry Pi 3B.

After I download the binaries, untar, move the geth folder into my `/usr/local/bin` and type `geth` I get the following error:

```
Command 'geth' is available in '/usr/local/bin/geth'
The command could not be located because '/usr/local/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
geth: command not found
```

If I cd into the folder and try running it I get the same error. If I run it with `sudo` I get `sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/geth: No such file or directory`.

The version I am installing is the following: geth-alltools-linux-arm7-1.9.13-cbc4ac26.tar.gz and I am using Ubuntu Server 20

Comment: That last one is telling "No such file or directory". what if you run `file /usr/local/bin/geth` ?

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/geth/geth`.

Comment: I tried that, but found via `file geth` that it is an executable and not a folder. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Two things:

1. I had installed an Ubuntu ARM64 OS so the geth version had to be changed from ARM7 to ARM64.
2. Run geth using `sudo`

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.